# Spark structured streaming, saving latest n records for querying

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am writing an application that reads messages from Kafka into Spark using structured streaming.

Incoming messages are trade-related FIX messages in a string format. They get converted to Java POJO.

The sample code below:

```
SparkSession spark = createSparkSession();

    // Subscribe to 1 topic
    Dataset<Row> df = spark
      .readStream()
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers)
      .option("subscribe", topics)
      .load();

    df.as(Encoders.STRING()).map(new MapFunction<String, OrderData>() {

        @Override
        public OrderData call(String arg0) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return OrderData(arg0);
        }
    }, Encoders.bean(OrderData.class));
```

My question is, How can I save last n records in memory in a DataSet, so that I can support Spark SQL on top of that DataSet?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that some thing like this will work:

```
dataset.writeStream().format("memory").queryName("orderdataDS").start()
```